# Hibernate could not create new user

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a problem when I want to create a new user in the databsase. When I go to use the save method.

> Estado HTTP 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not initialize a collection: [com.oceanic.domain.Usuario.encuestas#1]; SQL [select encuestas0_.idusuarios as idusuarios10_1_, encuestas0_.idencuestas as idencues1_1_, encuestas0_.idencuestas as idencues1_4_0_, encuestas0_.idempleado as idempleado4_0_, encuestas0_.idempleados as idemplea2_4_0_, encuestas0_.idusuarios as idusuarios4_0_, encuestas0_.idviajesprogramados as idviajes4_4_0_, encuestas0_.nota as nota4_0_ from encuestas encuestas0_ where encuestas0_.idusuarios=?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not initialize a collection: [com.oceanic.domain.Usuario.encuestas#1]

Comment: Post more info please.Post your related entities ? Probably there is a problem with entity mappings.

Answer (score 0):

While it is impossible to give you the root cause of your problem the error is thrown due to bad SQL, so things to check would be your query statment, DAO object, and hibernate mappings.
[InvalidDataAccessREsourceUsageException](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/dao/InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException.html)